# React component that can be updated by a prop or state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component where a user can fill out a form, but if they upload an image it will prefill some of the fields in the form.  So image a form with an entry for credit card number, but if the upload an image of their credit card it will fill out some fields.

So you might have something like:

```
const mapStateToProps = (response) => ({
  ccNumber: response.ccImage.ccNumber,
});
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  evaluateCcImage: props => dispatch(evaluateCcImage(props)),
})
```

But then I have a component

```
<div id="ccNumber">
  {this.props.ccNumber}
</div>
```

But if I want a user to be able to update this, I'd want it to be state.  Should I use `componentWillReceiveProps` to make `this.props.ccNumber` into `this.state.ccNumber` and then allow the user to edit it?

Comment: You should look into **[getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)**

Comment: Make use of componentDidUpdate  for updating the state, when the upload happens
successfully. You need to give a working codesandbox or code snippet link for better help

Comment: @simbathesailor `componentDidUpdate` would be a wrong event. If you set values of state from props here, you will trigger another render cycle

Comment: The general question relating the workflow would be, what if I enter `ccNumber` manually and then upload the image? What will be the golden source? UserInput or server's responce?

Comment: Rajesh -- that doesn't directly apply to my problem, but for the sake of simplicity let's say the image upload triggers the field to be overwritten.

Comment: you may be right, but there is this thing about getDerivedProps, you dont have access to previous props and previous state, which might be problem in this case. That's what I am  asking for more code and context here

Comment: As per my understanding, when the image upload happens, the UI is getting some information from backend which is obviously happening after  the mount. In that case, we need to compare if the API call has happened at the moment, then only update in the state. Again more context is required